# Static analysis of Javascript with Java

Tags: java, javascript

I need to do a static analysis of Javascript files using Java. Here I need to check whether the Javascript file has any function calls to document.write() or reference to properties like innerHTML etc. Can I use javax.script.* package to achieve this? or Which Java api do I need to use for Parsing? Also can you provide examples for the same?

Comment: As [Erwin says in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23132720/304) you are limited in what you can do. However, if you decide to pursue static analysis [there's a JavaScript AST package in Rhino](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/javascript-amd-module-dependency.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't statically analyze Javascript in the way you intend because Javascript is not a statically typed language.

You can check for `document.write()` but what if my code was this:

```
var whatever = document; whatever.write()
```

Or do you want to reject any function named `write()` even if it didn't write to the document?

Furthermore, Javascript has an `eval` function so you could always do:

```
var m = "ment"; 
eval("docu" + m + ".wri" + "te('hahahaha')");`.
```

How are you going to check for that?

Similarly, property access can be done in many ways.

Imagine this piece of code:

```
var x = document.children[0];
x.innerHTML = ...;
x["inner" + "HTML"] = ...;
var y = "inner";
x[y + "HTML"] = ...;
```

You're not going to be able to detect all those variants, and the hundreds more variants that you could make, using static analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer. Can this be achieved through any dynamic solution using Java? I just want to check whether the calls to these functions/properties is made. This is just to get the statistics of those function calls.

Comment: You can only do that by running the code and somehow counting the number of calls. There is a Javascript engine in Java but it doesn't emulate the browser well enough (I've never used to to emulate a browser, it may not have this functionality at all) to run most javascript scripts. Your best bet is to look into [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/), which does emulate a modern browser (but not in Java) - you may be able to plug your own code into it to do what you want.